# Unable to case generic type as parent type

Tags: c#

I have the following classes

```
public interface IEngine
{
    void DoSomething();
}
```

.

```
public interface IEngineFactory<T> where T : IEngine
{
    T Create();
}
```

.

```
public class FooEngine : IEngine
{
    public FooEngine(string id)
    {
        // do something with the id
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        // do something with the id
    }
}
```

.

```
public class EnginesSection : ConfigurationSection
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("engines", IsRequired = true)]
    public EnginesElement Engines
    {
        get { return (EnginesElement) this["engines"]; }
        set { this["engines"] = value; }
    }
}
```

.

```
public class EnginesElement : ConfigurationElement
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("foo", IsRequired = true)]
    public FooEngineElement Foo
    {
        get { return (FooEngineElement) this["foo"]; }
        set { this["foo"] = value; }
    }
}
```

.

```
public abstract class EngineElement : ConfigurationElement, IEngineFactory<T> where T : IEngine
{
    public abstract T Create();
}

public class FooEngineElement : EngineElement<FooEngine>
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("id", IsRequired = true)]
    public string Id
    {
        get { return (string) this["id"]; }
        set { this["id"] = value; }
    }

    public FooEngine Create()
    {
        return new FooEngine(Id);
    }
}
```

And a web.config that contains

```
<engineSection>
    <engines>
        <foo id="asdf" />
    </engines>
    <locales>
        <engine locale="en-US" type="foo"/>
        <engine locale="en-CA" type="foo"/>
    </locales>
</engineSection>
```

My intent is to map the locales specified in the `locales` section, to the appropriate engine. The engine that is selected is the engine that was created by the config element. So the `type` value in the `engine` element is the element name in the `engines` section. In the future, there will be different engines with different parameters. Each locale may only have one engine.

For example

```
<engineSection>
    <engines>
        <foo id="asdf" />
        <bar timeout="00:00:00.300" workers="6" />
    </engines>
    <locales>
        <engine locale="en-US" type="foo"/>
        <engine locale="en-CA" type="foo"/>
        <engine locale="en-GB" type="bar"/>
    </locales>
</engineSection>
```

My attempt to achieve this is this method:

```
IDictionary<string, string> engineLocales = GetEngineLocalesFromConfig();
IDictionary<string, IEngine> engines = GetEnginesFromConfig();
IDictionary<string, IEngine> mappedEngines = MapEngines(engineLocales, engines);

// ...
private static IDictionary<string, IEngine> GetEnginesFromConfig(EnginesElement enginesElement)
{
    var engines = new Dictionary<string, IEngine>();

    foreach (PropertyInformation property in enginesElement.ElementInformation.Properties)
    {
        var factory = property.Value as EngineElement<IEngine>;

        engines[property.Name] = factory.Create();
    }

    return engines;
}
```

So that we have

```
|----engineLocales-----|
         |---------engines---------|
+----------------------------------+
| locale | engine type | engine    |
+--------+-------------+-----------+
| en-US  | foo         | FooEngine |
| en-CA  | foo         | FooEngine |
| en-GB  | bar         | BarEngine |
+----------------------------------+
```

However, this does not work, because the case from `EngineElement<FooEngine>` to `EngineElement<IEngine>` fails. I don't want the code that maps these things to necessary be aware of the implementation.

Is there a way to achieve this type of dynamic mapping without knowing the exact implementation? If not, what alternatives do I have?

Comment: I don't understand your goal...

Comment: Bottom line: the cast fails because _`AbstractFoo<BarEngine>` is not `AbstractFoo<IEngine>`_. Depending on what `AbstractFoo<T>` is, you might be able to do what you want by declaring the type as an interface instead of an abstract base class (you can still implement the interface with the abstract base class). See the _many_ existing Q&A on Stack Overflow that address variance in generic types for more details.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I've updated my question to be more specific about what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: Unfortunately, knowing _why_ you want to cast from a more derived generic type parameter up to a base type doesn't change things. The fact remains that _you can't do that_. It's just not supported in generic classes or methods. You will need to declare a variant interface to accomplish something like that. If after researching variance in C# generic interfaces and making an attempt to address your scenario using that feature, you still continue to have problems, you can post a new question in which you include a good [mcve] showing what you've tried, and a _specific_ question about that code.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the desired behavior by using `IEngineFactory` all the way down the call stack. Because I didn't care about it's actual implementation, just its ability to `Create`.

I changed `IEngineFactory` to

```
public interface IEngineFactory
{
    IEngine Create();
}
```

`EngineElement` to

```
public abstract class EngineElement : ConfigurationElement, IEngineFactory
{
    public abstract IEngine Create();
}
```

`FooEngineElement` to

```
public class FooEngineElement : EngineElement
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("id", IsRequired = true)]
    public string Id
    {
        get { return (string) this["id"]; }
        set { this["id"] = value; }
    }

    public override IEngine Create()
    {
        return new FooEngine(Id);
    }
}
```

And the creation of the factory to

```
var factory = property.Value as EngineElement;
```